# Is it possible to generate an XML file with XSLT without xml namespaces declaration?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xslt stylesheet :

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <Parameters>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Parameters>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PrimitiveParameter">

    <!-- String -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:string'">
      <xsl:element name="StringParameter">
       <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:if test="Key">
          <xsl:attribute name="DomainKey">
            <xsl:value-of select="Key" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- DateTime -->
    <xsl:if test="Value/@xsi:type='xsd:dateTime'">
      <xsl:element name="DateParameter">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it produces this XML :

```
<Parameters xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <StringParameter name="field" DomainKey="Domaine">TNA</StringParameter>
    <DateParameter name="date">2011-12-14T00:00:00</DateParameter>
</Parameters>
```

I want to remove XML Namespace declarations :

```
<Parameters>   
  <StringParameter name="field" DomainKey="Domaine">TNA</StringParameter>
  <DateParameter name="date">2011-12-14T00:00:00</DateParameter>
</Parameters>
```

Is it possible ?

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case getting rid of the `xmlns="..."` should be as simple as removing the

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
```

from your `xsl:stylesheet` opening tag.  Literal result elements and `xsl:element` instructions that only specify a `name` (without a `namespace`) are subject to the namespace declarations that are in force at the point where they appear in the stylesheet XML document.

To get rid of the other unused namespace declarations you need to add another attribute to the `xsl:stylesheet`

```
exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xsi"
```

---

One other thing to note is that your tests for things like `Value/@xsi:type='xsd:string'` are exact string comparisons - if the source document uses a prefix other than `xsd`

```
<PrimitiveParameter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Value xsi:type="xs:string">...</Value>
</PrimitiveParameter>
```

then these will not match, even though semantically the XML is saying the same thing.  To handle this properly you would need to use a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon EE, and use tests like `element(Value, xsd:string)` to test the schema type of the element rather than the textual value of its `xsi:type` attribute.

Comment: - I remove the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" but there is no effect.

- I add the exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xsi" attribute and it works fine !

Thank you so much !